# Prove that if $X$ is a subset Maximally Linearly Independent of $V$, then $X$ is a basis of $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

I just want you to check if my proof is correct (or not) please.

> Let be $F$ a field and $V$ a vector space over $F$. Prove that if $X$
> is a subset Maximally Linearly Independent of $V$, then $X$ is a basis
> of $V$.

**My attempt:**

We suppose that $X$ is not a basis. Then, since $X$ is a subset of $V$, there exist another subset $S$ of $V$ such that, $Z=X \bigcup S$ is linearly independent and generates $V$.

But, that implies $X \subseteq Z$, so $X$ is not Maximally linearly independent. **(That's a contradiction)**.

\begin{align}
\therefore X \text{ is a basis of } V
\end{align}

Is correct my proof? I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I guess it is correct, but my issue is that the statement you use to prove the claim is equally potent. If $X$ is a subset of $V$, there exists another subset $S$ of $V$ such that $Z=S\cup X$ is independent and generates $V$. Did you prove this before?

Comment: @DonThousand I think that is a result for linearly independent subsets in finite dimensional vector spaces that I saw in the Hoffman's Book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative way:

> Suppose that $X$ is not a basis for $V$, that is, it does not generate the full space. Then there is $v \in V$ which cannot be written as a linear combination of the elements of $X$, meaning that $X \cup \{v\}$ is linearly independent, contradiction.